# React, react routing and HTML templates

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am working among a team on a large web projet.
These are the technologies involved:

- Meteor: Full-stack JavaScript framework
- MongoDB: DBMS
- React: included in Meteor as the following 2 main packages react v15.6.1 and react-router-dom v4.1.2

My question concerns the front-end part of the website and its integration with already developed early versions. The specifications of the front-end section were translated to hand drawn wireframes first, then digital ones using [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/).

While developing the first versions of the website, I used React and now I am in love with it *(and kind of stuck with it too to be honest :D)*.
I am not normally in charge of the front-end section of the project, but I will be responsible or integrating it with my already done work.

Knowing that the digital wireframes will be coded in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, my question is: Is there a way of integrating/translating/rewriting an HTML, CSS and JavaScript template to fit React?

My question basically boils down to; how to integrate an HTML, CSS and JS template into a React project?
If there is no way to do so, what would be the best approach: rewrite my code, or the template should be written in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do, is copy the HTML tags/elements from the file into React's return(){} and then add React components and modify some css to make it look like you want it to. Remember, React's return(){} is basically rendering HTML plus your own React components and Javascript to make them work the way you want them to.

However, if you just want to display a page, you can always

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';


static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
}
this.context.router.push('/page');
```

and set the path to direct to the HTML page in your route.js file.